# Is there an Android equivalent of the RCTJavaScriptDidLoadNotification event in react-native?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

When writing native iOS modules for react-native it's possible to subscribe to the `RCTJavaScriptDidLoadNotification` notification. This allows you to perform some additional native setup once the JS bundle has been loaded into the environment.

As far as I can see there's nothing equivalent when writing Android modules (unless it has a different name). There's `initialize` which you can override from `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` but this seems to be called before the JS bundle has been loaded.

Is there an Android equivalent of the `RCTJavaScriptDidLoadNotification` notification/event?

Answer (score 0):

You should try **[onReactContextInitialized](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactInstanceManager.java#L130)**

```java
@Override
public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Here's your valid ReactContext");
}
```